# PHP counter Twig equivalent

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

Hello I would like do something like that with my Twig template

```
<?php
    for( $i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
        // Not display the first number
        if( $i <= 1 ) {
            continue;
        }
        // Displaying numbers from 2 to 5
        echo $i ,'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you have tried already ? You have to show research efforts and ask why your solution (or attempt) is not working.

Comment: @avcajaraville Yes of course. I googled my search before ask my question to others and I also read the Twig documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you can use this to iterate numbers

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also from the documentation you can add conditions like this

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users if user.active %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So if you combine the two you end up with something like this.

```
{% for i in 0..5 if i<= 1 %}
    * {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Untested but should work.
THe documentation : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Answer (score 0):

If you literally just want to skip the first iteration, you can just do

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
```

or

```
{% for i in 0..5 if loop.index0 %}
```

But assuming you want to actually do something more useful like some processing on the first iteration, then just only echo `$i` on subsequent iterations, this should work:

```
{% for i in 0..5 %}
    This is printed every time...
    {% if (loop.index0) %}
        ...but this is only printed when $i > 0: {{ i }}<br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

There's not a "continue" keyword or any equivalent in Twig as far as I know.